# jQuery toggle and how to change text

Tags: jquery, toggle

I'm using the toggle feature to toggle back and forth between a div container that is hidden. When clicking on the 'show more' link it displays the div, and when clicking on the 'show less' link it hides the div.

Here is my code:

```
$('.transcript').addClass('hide')
$(".show-more").click(function(){
$(".transcript").toggle();
$(".transcript").removeClass('hide');
$(".show-more").html('show less');
});
```

The problem I am having is that when you click 'show more', it displays the hidden div and then changes the text of the link to 'show less'. However, then the text of that link remains as 'show less' when it should go back to 'show more' when the div is hidden.

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out, this code seems to work:

```
$('.transcript').addClass('hide');
$('.show-more').on('click', function() {
var $this = $(this);
if($('.transcript').is(':visible')) 
{
    $('.transcript').hide();
    $this.text('show more');
}
else
{
    $('.transcript').show();
    $this.text('show less');
}
});
```

Maybe now someone can tell me if that code is solid or if it needs work? It works fine on the front end, but I'm not sure if it's 'clean'.